# What the user_status column?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-registration

I was look in the `wp_users` table a `" user_status "` column...**( all contain zero )**

What works is this data?

[image]

Comment: A quick Google search or search here in the WordPress Stack Exchange would have revealed the answer - it's no longer used by WordPress core.

Comment: I'dont find, the results mixed my head... not using the only real thing anymore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `user_status` column in the `wp_users` table is no longer used by WordPress core - it just hasn't been removed. It may, or may not be used in the future. Best to leave it alone...

Comment: I am think wp used in the past "spam user", "banned user"?

Comment: Well, for 'active', 'inactive' and 'pending activation', I believe...

Comment: so now how to set activation action?

Comment: The other answer says that this column is used by WordPress core. How do you know that it is not used?

Comment: @Flimm - The function that Syed linked to is deprecated. If you read the top of the page in the link they provided it clearly states: "This function has been deprecated. Use wp_update_user() instead." and also states: "Deprecated as of 3.0.2 and should not be used"

As per my original answer, the column is still in the user database table, but it's no longer used by WordPress - they just haven't removed it from the DB. It may, or may not be used again in the future. But, for now, it's not used.

Comment: @Mat Just because the function `update_user_status` is deprecated absolutely does *not* mean that the database column `user_status` is deprecated. In fact, this column is referenced in [the documentation of the function `prepare_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/), for example.

Comment: @Flimm the function and the use of the user_status column is deprecated. https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-database-tables/

You don't have to accept that. But that's up to you! :D

Comment: @Mat Where in the WordPress documentation does it say that? I've seen so much code that uses this column, and I've seen WordPress documentation refer to this column, but I haven't seen any WordPress documentation or WordPress code that says it is deprecated. The article you linked to is an unofficial blog post with no publish date, I have no idea how accurate it is. For all I know, it copied this idea from this answer post.

Comment: @Flimm In the documentation link provided by the other answer, as you pointed out yourself. If you read it, it states "This function has been deprecated. Use wp_update_user() instead.". wp_update_user() has no reference to user_status and the previous page/link also states: "Previously used in core to mark a user as spam or "ham" (not spam) in Multisite." - note the 'PREVIOUSLY'. Now, you can either choose to accept that it is not used anymore or continue to argue a non-sensical point, but I don't have time to argue over this... It's not used by WordPress anymore. Simple.

Comment: @Mat Everything you are talking about is about the function `wp_update_user`, not the column `user_status`. The documentation says use `wp_update_user()` instead, from which you can modify `user_status`.

Comment: @Flimm NO. Read what I said,  read and understand the documentation correctly. "Previously used in core to mark a user as spam or "ham" (not spam) in Multisite." - this is referring to the column in the DB. "PREVIOUSLY USED"... You see that? "PREVIOUSLY"... Now go find some other useless thing to argue with someone... :'D

Comment: @Flimm I think I've provided plenty of links and evidence to suggest that it's no longer used. I think it's about time, now, that YOU provided something, other than just hearsay and personal opinion, to show where it is still being used by WordPress! Good luck! :D

Comment: @Flimm - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/ - Absolutely NO reference to 'user_status' just a BOOL for 'spam'... Isn't that strange? :'D

Comment: @Mat The sentence "previously used to mark a user as spam or ham" is under the desrciption of the function, not the column. Here's the link again: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_status/

Comment: @Mat WordPress documentation about the [Database Description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) mentions the `user_status` column but does not mention that it is deprecated.

Comment: @Mat As I mentioned before, the documentation for `prepare_query` lists `user_status` and does not mark it as deprecated, even though other options are `"all_with_meta"` is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to update the status of a user in the database. Used in core to mark a user as spam or "ham" (not spam) on multisite installs.

Status 0 is Ham 
Status 1 is Spam

Again, this will not work on single site installs.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_status#Mark_a_User_as_Spam

Comment: Downvoted as the answer refers to a function that is deprecated. "Deprecated as of 3.0.2 and should not be used."

Comment: @Mat make_ham_user hook and user status column in db is still used in current version. Also many websites still running on php 5 and old wp they are depreciated for newer versions only
click the shared link and read the docs 4th argument of the function $deprecated is added as of v3.0.2... func itself got depreciated in v5.3.0

Comment: @Mat v5.3.0 was released after my answer was posted

Comment: Show me one WordPress website that's sitting on a PHP 5 Server :'D

Comment: @Mat You serious?? https://www.php.net/usage.php click view stats and read today's stats 22% use php 5

Comment: @Mat 22% is huge share and I also know many sites that if upgraded to newer version will stop working... and the column is used in current wp ver

Comment: Show me 1 'WORDPRESS' website that's running on PHP 5... Not all websites that run on PHP 5, a WORDPRESS website... You serious!? :'D Most web hosts won't even allow you to run PHP 5 nowadays... Well, maybe in your country... Not in mine though.

Comment: @Mat 22% mean hundreds and millions of websites. I don't need to send you urls of the sites I worked on

Comment: I know exactly what 22% means in terms of the number of websites, but that's not what I claimed or asked, is it?

So the fact remains that you can't answer my question then? All I asked for was just 1 WORDPRESS website... But you can't... Because the fact is, you're talking s**t and making up numbers.

Comment: Syed, if you want to use the user_status column, that's up to you :'D

Comment: Upvoted because this post answer the question about _What the user_status column?_ even if there is link to deprecated function but that is good to know how and what is it for in previously.